# Port forwarding not working on Verizon FIOS router

Tags: ssh, router, port-forwarding, modem

We have a MacPro connected to a Verizon FIOS modem/router. We are trying to connect to it via `ssh` remotely. It is set to listen for ssh on port 23. It works fine using LogMeIn Hamachi.

But using the public IP address, we cannot get the computer to respond.

We tried setting it up like this:
[image]

But we keep getting `Operation timed out`

Comment: Why are you listening on port 23?

Comment: Because we have port 22 forwarded to another machine

Comment: Well, you should probably start performing some packet captures and/or examine firewall logs to see where things are breaking down. There's no way for us to give you any further recommendations with the information you've provided.

Comment: Hamachi doesn't *need* port forwarding to work, are you certain the port-forwarding is working, rather than Hamachi doing fine without it?

Comment: @Paul, maybe I wasn't clear: It already works fine with Hamachi, no forwarding needed. But we want it to work globally without having to use Hamachi.

Comment: When I changed the listening port back to 22, it works fine.

Comment: @Ze'ev It is likely that Verizon block port 23 themselves as it is "unsafe" (though the notion of a port being unsafe is absurd).  Using high ports is often the way to go - 2222 or something.

Comment: 2222 doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha! Figured it out.

In the router port forwarding configuration, you have to set

1. Source Ports: Any
2. Destination Ports: the port you want to use
3. Forward to Port: Same as incoming port

Comment: "Source ports: Any" solved this problem for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me (e.g., ssh user@WAN_IP -p CUSTOM_SSH_PORT)

Select IP from Menu: pick the server to port forward: note, assigned static IP

Application to forward: Custom Ports

Click "Advanced >>>" button

Source Ports: Any

Destination Ports: CUSTOM_SSH_PORT

Forward to Port: 22

The entry after being added reads:

Destination Port: CUSTOM_SSH_PORT
TCP Any -> CUSTOM_SSH_PORT