# Port forwarding not working on FIOS modem at home for web server

Tags: port-forwarding

Updated

- In the linux pc, start webserver. In browser, http://localhost:1234/
  loads fine.
- Setup nginx, http://192.168.5.155:80 is directed to localhost:1234 now.
- But using my external ip http://77.88.99.100:1234/ still says refuse to connect.
- The Fios modem is set like this: Destination Ports 1234, TCP Any -> 1234
- Tried this but no luck [Port forwarding not working on Verizon FIOS router](https://superuser.com/questions/869417/port-forwarding-not-working-on-verizon-fios-router)

Comment: so it sounds like you haven't even gotten around to testing the port forwarding because you are stuck getting the webserver to work when used from the lan using the lan IP. what is the output of `netstat -ntlup` from the linux box? is the local port bound to 0.0.0.0 or 192.168.5.155, or is it bound to 127.x.y.z?

Comment: @FrankThomas just for port 1234, the cmd output is 127.0.0.1:1234, its foreign address is 0.0.0.0:*

Comment: ok that means that it will only respond to localhost or 127.0.0.1. its a common secxurity default that people have problems with. what webserver software do you have running? Apache or nginx? the details on how to bind the port to 0.0.0.0 are different for each webserver product.

Comment: no i haven't turn on nginx yet, just started a node.js server. Let me do some research, thx !

Comment: ah ok I get it, your developing a local node app, and you;ll reverse proxy traffic to it via nginx. gotcha. once you have that complete, you'll be able to access the app via the LAN IP address. and if everything is working fine with your port forwarding, you should be able to access it from the Internet on the public IP as well. just be aware, for most home-grade routers, you cannot test port forwarding rules from inside your LAN (unless your router supports NAT hairpinning) so go to a coffee shop or friends place when you get to testing the public accessibility. good luck!

Comment: So your nginx is listening on TCP\80, but, your port forward rule is pointing to TCP\1234 (which won;t work because the node app only listens for localhost connections). revise your port forwarding rule to change the local port to 80. so the router points to nginx (192.168.5.155:80), and nginx points to your node app (localhost:1234). then go to canyouseeme.org to test that your publlic IP has a listener on TCP\1234 (77.88.99.100:1234). note that you don;t HAVE to use 1234 for the public connections; you could probably use 80 if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Linux machine to see if there's anything stopping communication from happening on port 1234 such as a firewall, route table or similar. Generally, if you're getting a message stating that the connection is refused it means that you're getting through to the machine but it's just not accepting the connection on that socket. T